# Undefined offset issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Any Budy Here to help me
I am facing offset issue .

```
$cookie = Cookie::get('referral');

$referred_by = $cookie ? \Hashids::decode($cookie)[0] : null;

return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    'referred_by' => $referred_by
]);
```

Comment: You should also paste the exact error you're getting, there are 5 places you could be getting the error there.

Comment: Errors are made to be read. Post the entire error including the line where it occurs (point for us in your snippet the line that error message points)

Comment: $referred_by = $cookie ? \Hashids::decode($cookie)[0] : null;@  this line showing updated message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cookie = Cookie::get('referral');

$referred_by = $cookie ? (isset(\Hashids::decode($cookie)[0]) ?? null) : null;

return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    'referred_by' => $referred_by
]);
```

Comment: @Thanks for this